# Looping through the properties of an IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Let's say I have an IQueryable with a bunch of properties obtained through LINQ, how can I loop through these properties?

I have tried:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in rows.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
                var name = propertyInfo.Name;
            }
```

This doesn't seem to work though and nothing is returned. I need a way to retrieve the name of values of all properties inside of the IQueryable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `rows` is the result of the query, you'd need to use [Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var type = rows.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
{
   //...
```

This is because the result will be an `IQueryable<T>`, not the value itself.  Extracting out the generic type will likely allow you to get the properties explicitly.

Comment: how do I get the value of the properties? var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null); doesnt seem to work..

Comment: @Dimo You'd have to start enumerating the IQueryable, and pass in each instance.  `foreach(var row in rows) { var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(row, null); }`